# roboflow not generating new version

Tags: roboflow

Please help me, when I generate a new version of my dataset, roboflow takes a long time with only 14 images and then generates a new empty version with no images.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XjO5.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVDcr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you help me understand your user flow? When Generating a new version of a dataset you should be taken to the "Generating New Version" page where you have the option to add more source images, rebalance train/test/split, preprocess, augment, and generate.

Addressing the images you attached with `unused classes` 3-7, if the question here is to remove the unwanted classes, you can do this by clicking `Add preprocessing step` and selecting `modify classes` to remove or override a name